# Какой Opensource'ный БД выбрать для Asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-mvc

Работаю сейчас исключительно с базой MSSQL и проблем не было пока не пришел заказ который надо было развернуть на сервер у себя и конечно надо купить лицензии вот тут пошло, само только MSSQL на процессор 25000$, это очень дорого. Есть большой потребность использовании опенсоурсной БД который сработался бы без проблем с Asp.net mvc5. Посоветуйте пожалуйста какой Бд наиболее подходит для проектов средних и больших? и учитывая порог вхождения

Comment: sql server express бесплатная. возможно ее вполне будет достаточно. с учетом того, что многое можно кешировать, и не делать запросы к базе данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какие данные вы там хранить хотите? Без этого сложно что-то сказать.

Для документоориентированных есть базы вроде: RethinkDB, Riak, arangodb. И все они бесплатны.

Мы лично для своих онлайн игр используем RethinkDB. Очень прост в понимании. ReQL язык запросов похож на SQL. В случае чего не сложно докрутить кластеризацию с репликацией/щирдингом.

Из традиционных SQL бесплатных баз есть MySQL, PostgreSQL.

Хотя, многие переходят с MySQL на PostgreSQL. Есть ещё монга, но я ёё не недолюбливаю, поэтому не могу её советовать.

Comment: Здравствуйте! @Suvitruf А какие данные вы там хранить хотите? -обычные текстовые, числа, дата ... ну в основном БД для CRM систем

Comment: @EmirMamashov тогда MySQL - самое простое и быстрое решение.

Comment: документоориентированные еще mongodb и couchbase. монгу пинал тимлид за поведение на действительно больших объемах данных, коучбейз пну лично я, потому что это просто невозможно администрировать. Еще видел в списках OrientDB, но он, насколько понимаю, в первую очередь графовый.

Comment: @Etki я монгу не люблю. У меня к ней вопросы были по поводу репликации вроде.

Comment: @Suvitruf MySql хороший вариант, а он для больших приложении пойдет?

Comment: @EmirMamashov вполне. Большинство Российских компаний его и используют.

Comment: @Suvitruf ясно спасибо, надо попробовать

Comment: @Suvitruf вот тимлид на то же жаловался

Answer (score 1):

Какие предполагаются объемы БД? Если небольшие - то MS SQL Server Express бесплатен.

Если нужны большие объемы и бесплатность одновременно - то PostgreSQL.

А уточнение к вопросу - "для Asp.net mvc5" - бессмысленно. Asp.net mvc5 будет работать с любой СУБД, для которой есть ADO.NET драйвер.

Comment: Здравствуйте! @Pavel был вариант MS SQL Server Express, но БД будет большой.  "Asp.net mvc5 будет работать с любой СУБД, для которой есть ADO.NET драйвер." - не думаю что для всех оно существует а также документация примеры и именно с использованием  asp.net mvc5.

Comment: @EmirMamashov  существует что?

Comment: ADO.NET драйвер

Comment: @EmirMamashov а если этого драйвера не существует - то и БД для .NET все равно что не существует.

Comment: вот именно то что я уточнил что "для Asp.net mvc" имеет смысл, поскольку если бы не уточнил то ответы были-бы и другие БД которые как вы говорите не существует(для .NET)

Comment: @EmirMamashov не было бы других БД в ответах. У вас же тэг `c#` стоит

Comment: да вы совершенно правы, я уже забыл об этом. наверное забыл потому что я сначала писал вопрос, далее метки прикреплял)

Answer (score 0):

Например, SQL Server Express - бесплатный.
Использовался в публичном картографическом сервисе с относительно большой нагрузкой и объемом данных.  На сайте Microsoft есть подробное описание - [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/danmark/cases/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-Express/Mail.ru/Mail.ru-Microsoft/4000005498).

Другой вариант - облачные сервисы Azure. Посмотрите [Data & Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/pricing/calculator/) -- есть разные возможности для работы с любыми объемами данных.

Comment: Здравствуйте! @Stack был вариант MS SQL Server Express, но БД будет большой

Comment: обновил ответ: посмотрите сервисы azure.

Comment: Не забудьте близкого родственника MSSQL-я - SYBASE ASE, у которого  тоже есть express, и тоже со своими ограничениями (база до 5GB)